# Websocket (socket.io) vs HTTP(S) time performance

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, websocket, https, socket.io

We are trying to achieve a faster response time for a server call, and we opted to move the HTTP functionality to Websockets through socket.io.

Strangely enough, even though the general opinion is that Websockets should be faster especially since there's no handshake and any other connection setup functionality, our results don't show this, and actually HTTP edges out better since consecutive requests get back faster.

The backend is in Node.js with compression enabled (`app.use(compression())`), while the socket.io server is initalized with the deflate extension, as:

```
const io = new Server(server, {
  serveClient: false,
  pingInterval: 5000,
  pingTimeout: 10000,
  allowEIO3: true,
  cors: {
    origin: config.cors.origins,
    credentials: true,
  },
  perMessageDeflate: {
    threshold: 2048, // defaults to 1024

    zlibDeflateOptions: {
      chunkSize: 8 * 1024, // defaults to 16 * 1024
    },

    zlibInflateOptions: {
      windowBits: 14, // defaults to 15
      memLevel: 7, // defaults to 8
    },

    clientNoContextTakeover: true, // defaults to negotiated value.
    serverNoContextTakeover: true, // defaults to negotiated value.
    serverMaxWindowBits: 10, // defaults to negotiated value.

    concurrencyLimit: 20, // defaults to 10
  },
});
```

The socket listens like this:

```
io.use(async (socket, next) => {
  try {
    const userId = await socketAuthentication(socket.request);
    socket.on('search', async ({ data }) => {
      const response = await app.locals.searchController.search(data, userId);
      socket.emit('search', { ...response });
    });
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

While express listens for the respective HTTP request normally, through a router which then calls the same controller function (`await app.locals.searchController.search(data, userId)`), so no difference there.

The server is in AWS, on an EC2 instance behind nginx, and with SSL.

Below are the results for the same request, done sequentially 32 times:

[image: time results]

Are we missing anything? I thought that the deflate configuration could have something to do, since there is a general opinion of not having it enabled (socket.io from version 3 and up disables it).